# Data for foreach loop returning empty yet there is data in the table laravel 8

Tags: laravel

i want to display a product with all its attributes in a page.i am using for each loop to display the data using a variable I have defined in the relationship.the problem is after fetching the data its unable to display the data on the browser.i havent understood where i have gone wrong..kindly assist.
the method in the controller

```
public function show($id)
{
    $merchadisedata=Merchadise::find($id);

        
    return view('backend.merchadise.productattributes')->with(compact('merchadisedata'));
}
```

the variable in the product model that defines the relationship,i have imported the productattributemodel class at the top

```
public function merchadiseattributes() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Productattribute::class);
}
```

the foreach loop in the blade file that show the data

```
<table id="admindatatables" class="table table-bordered  display nowrap" width="100%">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name </th>
            <th>Attribute Size</th>
            <th>Attribute Stock</th>
            <th>Attribute Price</th>
            <th>Attribute Sku</th>
            <th>Attribute Status</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ( $merchadisedata->merchadiseattributes as $attribute)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $attribute->merchads->merch_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $attribute->productattr_size}}</td>
                <td>{{ $attribute->productattr_stock }}</td>
                <td>{{ $attribute->productattr_price}}</td>
                <td>{{ $attribute->productattr_sku }}</td>
                <td>{{ $attribute->productattr_status}}</td>
                
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    
</table>
```

Comment: dd($merchadisedata->merchadiseattributes) to see if there is any data

Comment: can you share your tablestructure from mercadise and products, please?

Comment: @flakerimi it shows the following  Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1517 ▼
  #items: []
}

Comment: @stephenwaweru99 please post your table structure or migration files.

Comment: this is the products migration table   $table->id();
            $table->string('merch_name');
            $table->string('merch_code');
            $table->string('merch_image');
            $table->boolean('merch_isactive')->default('0');;
            $table->text('merch_details');
            $table->string('merch_price');
            $table->integer('merchcat_id');
            $table->string('merch_splprice');
            $table->timestamps();

Comment: this is the productsattributes migration file$table->id();
            $table->integer('product_id');
            $table->string('productattr_size');
            $table->string('productattr_price');
            $table->string('productattr_stock');
            $table->string('productattr_sku');
            $table->boolean('productattr_status')->default('0');
            $table->timestamps();

Comment: items: [], so its not finding anything, try dd($merchadisedata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem what you have is that Laravel cant find the relation because the index name from your Productattribute table is not id. it is product_id.

Then you have declare in the model the new index name like that:

`return $this->hasMany(Productattribute::class, 'foreign_key', 'local_key');` means:

```
public function merchadiseattributes() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Productattribute::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}
```